# Getting the reference of a cell from inside a childview of the cell when a UITapGesture is triggered

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am trying to retrieve the data from a cell when a UITapGesture is triggered from within a child view of that particular cell. My current code is returning the wrong cell for each one in a way where I can't tell how it's being worked out. Sometimes it will change for the same cell.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "followerSeg" || segue.identifier == "followingSeg") {
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! FollowersFollowingVC
        let x = sender as! UITapGestureRecognizer
        let view = x.view!
        let cellone = view.superview as UIView?
        let cell = cellone?.superview as! PersonCell
        vc.userName = cell.person.profileName
        vc.userId = cell.person.id
        vc.segStatus = segue.identifier == "followerSeg" ? 0 : 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try to use UITableView's `indexPathForRowAtPoint` method. I've been working with objc/iOS for 5+ years now, but this is my first shot at Swift. Please forgive any syntax errors.

Assuming you have a property called `tableView`, the code is as follows:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "followerSeg" || segue.identifier == "followingSeg") {
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! FollowersFollowingVC
        let x = sender as! UITapGestureRecognizer
        let location = x.locationInView(self.tableView) as CGPoint
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(location) as NSIndexPath?
        let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! PersonCell
        vc.userName = cell.person.profileName
        vc.userId = cell.person.id
        vc.segStatus = segue.identifier == "followerSeg" ? 0 : 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Syntax is fine. Would upvote but I don't have the required reputation. Thank you.